# Where do principle axes of rotation point?

Tags: classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

When diagonalizing the moment of inertia tensor calculated relative to a point, where do the principle moments of inertia point? Below is 1) my interpretation of the diagonalization of the MoI tensor of a cube calculated relative to a corner, and 2) my (failed) attempt to apply this interpretation to a collection of discrete masses.

**Principle axes of cube calculated relative to corner**

The moment of inertia tensor of a cube calculated relative to a corner is 
$$
I_{ij}=\int_0^a \int_0^a \int_0^a \rho(r^2\delta_{ij}-r_i r_j)dV \implies \mathbb{I} = \frac{Ma^2}{12}\begin{bmatrix} 8&-3&-3\\-3&8&-3\\-3&-3&8\end{bmatrix}
$$
The eigenvectors of this matrix, i.e. the principle axes, are 
$$
\vec{a}^{(1)}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\quad
\vec{a}^{(2)}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix},\quad
\vec{a}^{(3)}=\begin{bmatrix} -2\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\vec{a}^{(2)}$ and $\vec{a}^{(3)}$ are determined only to lie in a plane perpendicular to $\vec{a}^{(1)}$.

My interpretation: Because we used the point (0,0,0) as the origin for integration, one of the principle axes (the 'master' axes) must pass through that point AND ALSO through the center of mass. The master axis is clearly $\vec{a}^{(1)}$.  The other two vectors are perpendicular to the master axis and also pass through the center of mass.

Note that axes perpendicular to the cube faces and passing through the center of mass are also principle axes of rotation.  These axes are $\vec{b}^{(1)}=[1,0,0],\quad\vec{b}^{(2)}=[0,1,0],\quad$ and $\quad\vec{b}^{(3)}=[0,0,1]$.  But because we didn't use the point $(a/2,a/2,a/2)$ as our origin for calculating the MoI tensor, those vectors are not eigenvectors in our problem.

**Discrete arrangement of masses**

Consider three equal masses positioned at (a,0,0), (0,a,2a), and (0,2a,a).  The moment of inertia tensor for this arrangement is 
$$
\mathbb{I} = ma^2\begin{bmatrix} 10&0&0\\0&6&-4\\0&-4&6\end{bmatrix}
$$
The eigenvectors of this matrix are 
$$
\vec{a}^{(1)}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},\quad
\vec{a}^{(2)}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad
\vec{a}^{(3)}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}
$$

The center of mass of the system is at $R_{CM}=(\frac{1}{3},1,1)$.  However, *none of the discovered principle axes point from the origin to the center of mass.*  If I were to mount these masses on a rotation axis with one end of the axis fixed at the origin, I would expect one principle axis to point along $\hat{e}=(\frac{1}{3},1,1)$.  I can't imagine that any of the eigenvectors I found for this system would describe an axis that produces rotations with $\vec{L}$ aligned to $\vec{\omega}$ if one point of the axis were pinned to the origin.  What is wrong with my interpretation?

One possibility: For a body with an axis- or axes-of-symmetry, IF the inertia tensor is calculated using a point along an axis-of-symmetry as reference (such as for the cube above), then one eigenvector will pass from the reference point through the center of mass.  But, IF the body does not posses an axis of symmetry (such as the discrete masses), then the eigenvectors will pass through the center of mass, but no eigenvector will necessarily pass through the reference point.  This argument is *post-hoc*, however, and I do not like it.

Comment: The threes normalized eigen vectors bild rotation matrix , so you just rotate your body fixed coordinate system  to a new coordinate system ,both coordinate system are located at the center of mass

Comment: Hi @Eli.  I think I understand your comment.  When using the cube corner as the reference for calculation of the MoI tenser, why does a resulting eigenvectors point towards the corner? There are equally valid eigenvectors along (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,0,1).  I know one answer to this question is 'because the math says so', but I'm looking for something deeper, if possible.  The only other answer I see is summarized in my final paragraph in the original question.